# Given a, b, c are positive number, $abc=a+b+c$ prove $ab+4bc+9ac≥36$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I know how to solve it using Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality (I find coefficient 1, 4, 9 for which the square of the sum of their square roots is exactly 36)?

But is there another way that involves less guessing and perhaps less complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an elementary-algebra-level solution . . .

Not instant, but it has the advantage of not requiring much sophistication.

Suppose $a,b,c > 0$ are such that $abc=a+b+c$.

Let $f=ab+4bc+9ac-36$.

Our goal is to show $f\ge 0$.

From $abc=a+b+c$, we get $c(ab-1)=a+b$, hence $ab > 1$, and
$$c=\frac{a+b}{ab-1}$$
Replacing $c$ in $f$, we get
$$f=\frac{(a^2+4)b^2-(24a)b+(9a^2+36)}{ab-1}$$
so it remains to show $g\ge 0$, where
$$g=(a^2+4)b^2-(24a)b+(9a^2+36)$$
Regarding $g$ as a quadratic function of $b$, it suffices to show $D\le 0$, where $D$ is the discriminant
$$D=(-24a)^2-4(a^2+4)(9a^2+36)$$
Expanding $D$ and then factoring yields
$$D=-36(a+2)^2(a-2)^2$$
so $D\le 0$, which completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Less complicated... unlikely.

Less guessing... [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). Use the Lagrange multipliers to calcualte the minimum of $$f(a,b,c)=ab+4bc+9ac$$ given the condition that $$g(a,b,c)=abc-a-b-c=0.$$

That is, you get the Lagrangian function $L(a,b,c,\lambda)=ab+4bc+9ac-\lambda(abc-a-b-c)$, and the calculate the partial derivatives, and equate them to $0$, so you get the equations:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = b+9c-\lambda bc+\lambda = 0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}=a+4c-\lambda ac+\lambda=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}=4b+9a-\lambda ab+\lambda = 0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = a+b+c-abc=0$$

Solve the equations, and get the minimum value which is $\geq 36$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=bc,q=ca,r=ab$.

$1=1/p+1/q+1/r$ and $p,q,r>0$.

Enough to show $p+4q+9r\ge 36$.

To make LHS zero-dimensional, multiply $1=1/p+1/q+1/r$.

Then we want to show $(p+4q+9r)(1/p+1/q+1/r)\ge 36$ but this is just direct consequence of Cauchy-Schwartz.

(Maybe you made a similar proof, but I want to emphasize that what you have to do is more obvious after this substitution, which is natural)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=2x$, $b=3y$ and $c=z$.

Thus, $$2x+3y+z=6xyz$$ and we need to prove that
$$6xy+12yz+18xz\geq36$$ or
$$xy+2yz+3xz\geq6\cdot\frac{6xyz}{2x+3y+z}$$ or
$$(2x+3y+z)(xy+2yz+3xz)\geq36xyz,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$(2x+3y+z)(xy+2yz+3xz)\geq6\sqrt[6]{x^2y^3z}\cdot6\sqrt[6]{xy(yz)^2(xz)^3}=36xyz.$$